# JavaScript Ajax request from Firefox browser action popup

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to create an add-on for Mozilla Firefox. I have created a popup for browser action toolbar icon. Now I just want to make an AJAX request on clicking a button in the popup. How can I do this?

I have tried something.

My popup.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo">
<h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/bestOfDeals", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

AJAX request returns some JSON data
But this is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Also added screenshot of my browser action popup.
[image]

manifest.json

```json
{
  "description": "description",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Assistant",
  "version": "1.0",
  "homepage_url": "https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/logo.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "notifications",
    "desktop-notification": {
      "description": "Needed for creating system notifications."
    }
  ],  

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/logo.png",
    "default_title": "Assistant",
    "default_popup": "popup/popup_menu.html"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/"],
      "js": ["content_scripts/content-script.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Show us your manifest.json please. And also the json data that was returned.

Comment: Add the site that you are sending the request to, to your permissions. Or just add "<all_urls>" to allow requesting any url.

Comment: @Forivin "web_accessible_resources": [
  "http://localhost/bestOfDeals"
 ]
added this to the manifest.json , but no use ..still not working

Comment: No, try to add `"http://localhost/*"` to your permissions array.

Comment: @Forivin I tried , but no use.

Comment: What does it say in the debug console?

Comment: I have no idea about debug console. I am a beginner. Sorry.

Comment: When you go to `about:debugging` and load your extension, there is a Debug button. When you press it a debug console should pop up. You'll probably find some warning or error messages in there.

Comment: @Forivin TypeError: e.contains is not a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148504/discussion-between-dexter-and-forivin).

Comment: Inline scripts are not permitted in extension HTML pages (e.g. popup.html). Move your JavaScript into a separate file. If you looked in the console, you should have seen an error explicitly stating this.